# Como gerenciar Sessão com Session em aplicações C# para desktop e não web?

Tags: c#, session

Eu não consigo encontrar um exemplo de uso do objeto Session para aplicações desktop, todos os que eu encontro são para aplicações feitas em C# para a web com asp, etc.

Alguém sabe como verificar se um usuário está autenticado no programa ao abrir o mesmo?

Eu sei que é possível fazer isso com o objeto Session, porém só encontro exemplos pra Web e não consigo implementar uma verificação de sessão.

Comment: Já solucionou seu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível trabalhar com Session da mesma forma que você trabalha na Web.

Recomendo criar uma classe estática com propriedades estáticas(get e set). Essas propriedades vão ficar disponíveis enquanto o programa estiver “rodando”.

Exemplo abaixo.

Sua classe que gerencia as sessões pode ficar assim:

```
public static class SessaoApp
{

    public static int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    public static string UsuarioNome { get; set; }

    public static string Login { get; set; }

    public static string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Na sua implementação ficaria

```
       seuTextBoxEmail = SessaoApp.Email;
       seuTextBoxLogin = SessaoApp.Login;
       seuTextBoxNome = SessaoApp.UsuarioNome;
       seuTextBoxUsuarioId = SessaoApp.UsuarioId;
```