# Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies

Tags: c#, session, cookies

Qual a diferença entre **Sessions** e **Cookies**? Em qual circunstancia devo usar?

Comment: Sessão é usado para autenticação de usuários e cookies costuma ser usando para armazenar dados alguns dados de sites, como propagandas e outros tipos. (Basicamente)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Cookies

De maneira bem simplificada, *cookies* são pequenos dados que são enviados pelo servidor Web para um cliente, de forma que este cliente devolva o mesmo dado na(s) requisição(ções) seguinte(s).

Quando usar? Basicamente quando você precisar de um pequeno dado que seja devolvido pelo cliente nas requisições seguintes. Seja uma mera informação de que ele já viu um *popup* chato, seja um inibidor para não contar uma nova visita.

Cookies em geral não são confiáveis. Eles podem ficar armazenados por dias, ou o cliente pode simplesmente não aceitá-los (na verdade não devolver nem gravar os dados), ou mesmo o usuário pode modificar estes dados.

Como a pergunta é uma comparação entre duas coisas distintas, não vou entrar em detalhes profundos do que é um Cookie, mas aqui tem mais algumas informações:

[Indicações de uso de cookies?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106906)

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie_HTTP

### Sessions

"Sessões", provavelmente no contexto pretendido na pergunta, são usualmente relacionadas a se manter dados do usuário numa aplicação, mesmo que este mude de página.

Naturalmente, aplicações Web são compostas de páginas totalmente independentes umas das outras. Eventualmente algumas páginas podem enviar informações para as seguintes, por exemplo em formulários, na forma de parâmetros de *query* (método GET), ou no corpo das requisições (método POST).

Além disto, as aplicações mais modernas fazem requisições AJAX, que são similares a GET, POST e outros métodos, mas sem sair da página.

Estas técnicas por si só são um pouco limitadas para se manter estados mais complexos, como um carrinho de compras, ou para saber se o usuário fez *login* num sistema, para isto se introduziu o conceito de *sessions*

A pergunta se refere ao C#, mas pegando desde os "primórdios" das aplicações Web, por exemplo com o ASP clássico, se usavam as sessões basicamente por duas maneiras: Ou incluindo um "número especial" em todos os links e formulários, que identificava aquele usuário, carregando a informação para as páginas seguintes, e/ou usando Cookies. As técnicas continuam parecidas até hoje, independentemente da linguagem utilizada.

Em casos mais complexos, pode se validar se o navegador do usuário se identifica sempre da mesma forma, ou se o IP de cada requisição é sempre o mesmo, cada técnica com as suas vantagens e desvantagens.

O que importa neste contexto é que sempre, ao ter uma nova página requisitada, o servidor saiba que há uma continuidade entre as requisições anteriores feitas pelo mesmo usuário.

[Como funciona a sessão em navegadores web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26610/como-funciona-a-sess%c3%a3o-em-navegadores-web)

[Qual é a diferença, na prática, entre Session e Application?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-na-pr%c3%a1tica-entre-session-e-application?s=1|0.0000)

[Como gerenciar Sessão com Session em aplicações C# para desktop e não web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70900/como-gerenciar-sess%c3%a3o-com-session-em-aplica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-c-para-desktop-e-n%c3%a3o-web?s=1|0.8594)

Answer (score 4):

**Cookie** é um mecanismo de armazenamento de suas variáveis do lado do cliente. É armazenado fisicamente no computador do cliente pelo navegador. Diferentes usuários no mesmo computador podem ler/utilizar o mesmo cookie.

Por conta disso (algumas observações):

- Você não deve armazenar dados sensíveis no cookie.
- Você não deve armazenar dados que pertence a uma conta de usuário.
- O cookie não tem efeito sobre os recursos do servidor.
- Cookie expira na data que você especificar.

A **Session** é também um mecanismo de armazenamento de suas variáveis, porém do lado do servidor. Por padrão, a session armazena os seus dados na memória do servidor. Mas você pode configurar para armazenar pelo SQL Server, por exemplo.  O mesmo usuário pode executar dois ou mais navegadores e cada navegador tem a sua própria sessão.

Ou seja:

- Você pode guardar dados sensíveis em sessão.
- Você não deve salvar tudo em sessão. que é desperdício de recursos do servidor.
- Após o usuário fechar o navegador, o *timeout* fará com que todas as informações sejam apagadas. Por padrão, esse tempo é de 20 minutos.

A circunstância de uso vai depender do seu escopo e o quê você vai armazenar...