# Session C# como funciona?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, tempo-de-vida

Qual é o tempo de vida de uma Session em ASP.NET MVC, e como descobrir descobrir o tempo restante e como adicionar mais tempo a Session (caso seja possível)?

Existe uma outra forma de guarda valor que seja mais performática?

Comment: Cara, Será que você não está confundindo session com cookies não? porque a session tanto em php e ASP.NET funciona da mesma forma: A session após ser criada ela gera um valor para identificação de cada usuário e não tem tempo para expirar só expira após usuário fechar o browser, quando o usuário fecha o browser destrói a session ativa e após ele acessar novamente é criada outra session com valor diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possivelmente duplicada? (Este link pode te ajudar também) [Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115190/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sessions-e-cookies/115197#115197)

Tratando-se de web, você pode alterar o valor do *timeout* da session através do `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Por padrão, o tempo é de 20 minutos.
Quanto a obter o tempo restante para terminar a session, existem várias maneiras, você teria que ser mais específico em relação a isso. Uma solução seria controlar o tempo via javascript. Mas se você quiser, por exemplo, redirecionar o usuário depois da session terminar, pode utilizar o  `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` e fazer tal validação..

EDIT:

Não, até onde eu sei, não é possível modificar o tempo da sessão em *tempo real*, visto que estamos falando em tempo de inatividade. Você define o tempo máximo de inatividade e, mediante passagem desse tempo, a sessão é finalizada.

Você pode implementar uma solução para manter sua sessão "viva" por tempo indeterminado também, basta "misturar" uma ação no MVC e fazer a chamada via jQuery:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult KeepSessionAlive() {
    return new JsonResult {Data = "Success"};
}
```

Comment: Hum, minha dúvida é como posso sabe via código, quanto tempo ainda falta para uma Session expirar, e se via código eu consigo adicionar mais tempo a Session ou simplesmente renovar o tempo de vida dela?

Comment: Editei a resposta com mais algumas informações, veja.

Answer (score 1):

O que seria uma sessão de um sistema ?

Sessão geralmente é utilizado para armazenar dados de usuário. É feito dessa forma pois os dados ficam no servidor, não possibilitando que outros usuários tenham acesso.

Você pode salvar a sessão da sua aplicação de várias formas:

InProc: armazena o estado da sessão na memória do servidor Web. Este é o padrão.

StateServer: armazena o estado da sessão em um processo separado chamado o serviço de estado ASP.NET. Isso garante que o estado da sessão é preservado se o aplicativo Web é reiniciado e também faz com que o estado da sessão disponível para vários servidores Web em um Web farm..

SQLServer: armazena o estado da sessão em um banco de dados SQL Server. Isso garante que o estado da sessão é preservado se o aplicativo Web é reiniciado e também faz com que o estado da sessão disponível para vários servidores Web em um Web farm..

Personalizado: permite que você especifique um provedor de armazenamento de costume..

Off : Sem sessão.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Dependendo do seu sistema você precisará de uma forma diferente.

Referente ao ciclo que vida, a sessão do usuário é apagada quando o mesmo desloga do sistema.

Gostaria de fazer uma ressalva, não é necessário usar Session você pode muito bem armazenar as informações de forma criptografada no cookie do browser.

Segue exelende tutorial de Eduardo Pires MVP

http://eduardopires.net.br/2015/04/pense-duas-vezes-antes-de-utilizar-sessions/