# Usar Cookies ou Session para guia de empresas?

Tags: php

Estou montando um guia de empresas e gostaria de saber se é melhor usar cookie ou session para guardar no cliente o id_cidade da qual ele pertence no primeiro acesso;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sessions são destruídas quando o navegador é fechado (exceto se o visitante marcar a opção de continuar de onde parou no navegador), já os cookies permanecem válidos pelo tempo que você determinar, ou até que o cliente os apague.

Sabendo disso, fica simples decidir qual utilizar. Pro seu caso, acredito que os cookies sejam mais interessantes, porque se você definir uma data de validade significativa, algum outro dia quando ele voltar, vai estar do jeito que ele deixou.

Lembre-se: nunca salve informações importantes (senhas ou dados pessoais) em texto plano em um cookie, de preferência nem salve esse tipo de dados do lado do cliente, pois, qualquer um com acessos ao computador poderá visualizar tais dados.

Não irei abordar esse assunto aqui porque foge da sua questão, mas caso tenha interesse, é só pesquisar aqui no Stackoverflow ou no próprio Google, você terá muita informação a respeito.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação @Clayderson Ferreira acredito que os cookies será a melhor opção mesmo

Comment: Rapazes, pensem na segurança... O que que impede do cliente alterar o valor do cookie? Se for usar cookie mesmo, aconselho encriptá-lo :)

Answer (score 0):

Possivel duplicada de [Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115190/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sessions-e-cookies/115197#115197) e [Session C# como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116224/session-c-como-funciona/116257#116257)

Copiando a breve explicação....

**Cookie** é um mecanismo de armazenamento de suas variáveis do lado do cliente. É armazenado fisicamente no computador do cliente pelo navegador. Diferentes usuários no mesmo computador podem ler/utilizar o mesmo cookie.

Por conta disso (algumas observações):

- Você não deve armazenar dados sensíveis no cookie.
- Você não deve armazenar dados que pertence a uma conta de usuário.
- O cookie não tem efeito sobre os recursos do servidor.
- Cookie expira na data que você especificar.

A **Session** é também um mecanismo de armazenamento de suas variáveis, porém do lado do servidor. Por padrão, a session armazena os seus dados na memória do servidor. Mas você pode configurar para armazenar pelo SQL Server, por exemplo. O mesmo usuário pode executar dois ou mais navegadores e cada navegador tem a sua própria sessão.

Ou seja:

- Você pode guardar dados sensíveis em sessão.
- Você não deve salvar tudo em sessão. que é desperdício de recursos do
  servidor.
- Após o usuário fechar o navegador, o timeout fará com que todas as
  informações sejam apagadas. Por padrão, esse tempo é de 20 minutos.

A circunstância de uso vai depender do seu escopo e o quê você vai armazenar...

**No seu caso**

Eu usaria Session, visto que estamos falando de um dado sensível...

Comment: Obrigado @Marllon Nasser