# Qual é mais seguro: session ou cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, segurança, session, cookies

Pensando em **segurança**, qual é a melhor opção para manter o usuário *logado* em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC, o *cookie* ou a *session*?

Comment: A session utiliza os cookies. Trabalham em conjunto, session no servidor e cookie no client.

Comment: Não entendi bem os negativos, mas tanta melhorar a pergunta pra ver se reverte.

Comment: Eu não negativei, mas marquei como duplicata, pois apesar de ambas perguntas serem diferentes, ainda sim a as respostas lá http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115198/3635 já explicam o porque uma ser supostamente mais segura que a outra, no entanto se discordar pode comentar aqui o seu ponto de vista :)

Comment: Jedaias, por gentileza, de uma olhada na minha resposta. `Sessions` do ASPNET não são uma boa, e ter marcado como resposta certa pode induzir outros à seguirem por um caminho ruim.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seguro é fazer certo. É dominar o assunto, conhecer todas as possíveis vulnerabilidades de cada mecanismo, saber quando e para que pode ser usado. Depende de cada caso.

Está usando SSL? Isto faz diferença na segurança.

## Qual é mais seguro

De qualquer forma eu prefiro sessões porque ela não fica armazenada no navegador. O *cookie* pode ser adulterado ou capturado. Mas dependendo de como ele for usado não tem problemas. Só nunca coloque informação sensível em um *cookie*.

Há controvérsias se deve usar um *cookie* para manter um usuário *logado* ou não, muitos sites importantes o fazem. Em tese é perigoso, mas é um perigo calculado e a segurança do usuário é que pode ser comprometida, não a segurança da aplicação web. Obviamente que não dá para tornar seguro algo que você não tem controle, então se realmente é necessário, não deixe o usuário "logado" por um mecanismo de controle no navegador.

Uma sessão pode usar um *cookie* para mantê-la ativa (depende da implementação, a atual usa). Ela se encarrega de fazer o que é necessário para manter a segurança dele, já tem um padrão comprovado de segurança. É uma forma mais abstrata de cuidar da segurança. Claro que ainda é necessário tomar alguns cuidados.

A sessão mantêm dados do lado do servidor, o que é uma enorme vantagem em relação aos *cookies* puros.

Eu vejo algumas pessoas dizerem para usar *cookies* e não *session*. Mas depende pra que será usado. As pessoas que tem experiência com isso vivem usando sessões. Claro que elas o fazem sabendo como usar, conforme eu disse logo no início.

É possível usar o ASP.NET Identity que é outra camada de abstração para obter um mecanismo de **controle de sessão** (sim, tem um controle de sessão embutido nela), entre outras coisas.

No fundo tudo usa *cookie*, é só escolher a camada de abstração que deseja.

Eu jamais diria para usar um ou outro sem saber o caso específico. Não vou aplicar uma "boa prática" geral. Cada mecanismo tem sua utilidade, vantagem e desvantagem. E principalmente não diria para não usar alguma coisa a não ser que exista um fato claro para não usar, se, por exemplo, o fornecedor tornou obsoleto e deu uma boa razão para não usar mais aquilo. O que não é o caso dos mecanismos citados na pergunta.

O assunto específico sobre o funcionamento e diferença entre os dois mecanismos já foi amplamente respondido aqui no SOpt. A pergunta não pede e não vou entrar em detalhes, afinal ela é mais específica. Por exemplo: [Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115190/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: no caso do login sem ssl , se um man in the middle rouba o cookie geralmente ele leva junto a sessão

Comment: @JohnDiego isso mesmo.

Comment: Não precisa nem de man in the middle, se for uma rede difusa como WIFI. Lembrando que nada é 100% seguro, existem técnicas capazes de roubar até mesmo com SSL.

Comment: @Daniloloko Sim, tem várias formas. Se bem que eu acho que o que você citou não deixa de ser um MITM.

Comment: @bigown, percebi a resposta como errada porque ela está, digamos mal formulada. A resposta em si está correta, mas precisei ler e reler umas 4 vezes para as palavras fazerem sentido. Acho que você podia melhorar um pouco principalmente os 2 últimos parágrafos. E adicionar sobre como a *session* utiliza o *cookie* enviado pelo navegador para reconhecer o usuário e guardar informações dele no servidor, temporariamente.

Comment: @tayllan Não sei se você que negativou. Negativo serve para resposta errada. Mas talvez resolveram negativar qualquer coisa, a outra também negativaram (é bem verdade que ela não fala o que foi perguntado, supõe coisas, mas ainda não acho que merece negativo). Eu não entrei em muitos detalhes porque a pergunta não é específica, não pergunta sobre os detalhes de como cada coisa funciona, como você sugere eu fazer. Mas depois eu dou uma melhorada.

Comment: @bigown, exato para resposta errada. Por isso negativei (sim, fui eu :)), porque eu li e não consegui compreender corretamente sua resposta. Fico aguardando sua edição para retirar o downvote.

Comment: @tayllan é que você disse que ela está correta, então o negativo ficou incoerente.

Answer (score -4):

Use o ASPNET Identity para gerenciar a autenticação do seus usuários. Ele já prevê vários quesitos de segurança e é super fácil de trabalhar com ele.

O ideal é usar cookie para gravar informações que não sejam de segurança. Por exemplo, preferencias do usuário, últimas páginas ou produtos vistos, quando esteve no seu site pela última vez - para um controle de contador de acesso, talvez.

E, se tratando de web, NÃO USE SESSION.

- Sessions são alocadas no Pool do IIS: quando a memória do AppPool é reciclada, seus dados armazenados em Session são liberados;
- Sessions são de acesso exclusivo: Sempre que se realiza um acesso à Session, todo pipe de execução é travado até que o acesso seja finalizado. Então, vc consegue ter apenas um acesso ao Session por vez. Imagine isso com vários usuários conectados simultaneamente.
- Session não são escaláveis: Como ela é alocada no AppPool, se hospedado em servidores escaláveis, essa informação não irá ser compartilhada entre outros hosts. Então se sua app usa Session, não é possível escalar horizontalmente.

Por isso usamos Cache ao invés de Session. E também é por tudo isso que existe várias soluções de Cache no mercado hoje.

Só não esqueça que Cache é compartilhado por toda aplicação. Então, se for fazer cache de dados de um usuário, faça simplesmente `Cache["DadosDoUsuario" + UsuarioId]` e seja feliz.

Você pode usar o [`System.Web.Caching.Cache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) por hora, e se precisar realmente investir em dados em Cache, partir para um RavenDB ou Redis.

Mas Session? Diga não às Sessions.

Comment: já ouviu falar de `Session-State`? você não é forçado à usar a `Session` `InProc`... pode usar o `SqlServer`, o `StateServer` ou até mesmo `Custom`

Comment: @TobyMosque, é exatamente de `Session-State` que me refiro. E estamos falando no contexto de aplicação, dentro do ASPNET. Session de SqlServer é outro tipo de Session, fora da aplicação.

Comment: Os que negativaram que, por gentileza, se pronunciem.

Comment: indepedente do `Session-State`, a `Session` continua a mesma, o que muda é a forma como são armazenados os dados... uma analogia seria Entity Framework e o EF Provider, modificar o Provider não faz com que o EF seja um ORM diferente, mas sim a forma como ele irá armazenar os dados.

Comment: Sim, exatamente. E o que eu postei é que recomendo fortemente a não usar o `System.Web.Caching.Cache`. Demais componentes de persistência de dados não estão em questão na minha postagem.

Comment: falando em Cache, até concordo com você em não utilizar o `System.Web.Caching.Cache`, também concordo que NoSQL pode ser uma alternativa para ao Cache... mas falando de Cache, o que você acha do `AppFabric In-Memory Cache Platform`, afinald se trata de uma solução de Cache distribuido gratuita da propria Microsoft?