# Melhor opções a SESSION?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, session

Sempre ouvi muita gente falar que SESSION não e performático e que não era aconselhável utilizar SESSION em aplicações .NET, mas até o momento não encontrei nada que eu possa utilizar no lugar da SESSION.

O que eu poderia usar no lugar da SESSION?

Comment: Dizer que session não é performático é como dizer que uma chave-de-fenda não é performática. Cada elemento de uma tecnologia tem seus usos específicos, e se alguém acha o Session uma coisa ruim de usar, é porque alguém usou o Session de forma errada.

Answer (score 1):

Tudo sempre depende. 
Hoje com ASP, dependendo da arquitetura, você pode trafegar informações de outras formas que não usam session, como viewbag, viewdata... Você precisa saber o que é necessário armazenar e por quanto tempo.

Abusar da session pode te causar problemas como estouro de memória, por exemplo, que irá causar a parada da pool, dependendo também das configurações do servidor.. quanto a questões de performance, pode ser que não seja muito performático, já que usa os recursos do servidor e lá está tudo em concorrência, com outras aplicações também, talvez... mas, essa é uma informação sem propriedade, de minha parte.

Particularmente uso cookies para armazenar muitos dados, claro: criptografados e sempre com HTTPOnly, assim, seu servidor tem acesso a esta informação e ela não fica disponível para captura por js, evitando XSS.

Você pode ler mais sobre cookies httpOnly aqui: 
https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/

Ou ter outros pontos de vista aqui:
[Qual é mais seguro: session ou cookie?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116891/qual-%C3%A9-mais-seguro-session-ou-cookie)

(=