# Como recuperar dados de um formulario invalido? PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário de cadastro que envio para um script php que faz o tratamento e grava no bd, o problema é que quando algum campo do formulário é invalido, eu direciono novamente para o formulário, mas ele fica em branco, pensei em gravar os campos na `$_SESSION`, mas parece ser meio gambiarra desse jeito.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não precisa ser $_SESSION, é só você colocar o $_POST ou $_GET, o que você tiver usando, na mesma página do formulário.

Comment: De fato SESSION tente a ser gambiarra (dependendo do caso e da técnica, até da pra usar se conseguir identificar unicamente). Se o formulário for na mesma requisição, a resposta abaixo serve. Se não for, precisa direcionar a pessoa com algum ID no URL e recuperar de algum lugar (DB, DB em memória, arquivo temporário etc);

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver utilizando o `$_POST` ou `$_GET` para enviar os dados, quando você valida os dados, identifica que estão inválidos e exibe o formulário novamente, os dados ainda estão disponiveis para você.

Assim dependendo de como é o seu formulário pode mudar um pouco, mas a idéia é fazer algo assim:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=isset($_POST['nome'])?$_POST['nome']:''?>" name="nome">
```

Conforme seus comentários, o form está em uma requisição diferente do processamento dos dados. Então a `$_SESSION` é uma alternativa.
Não ficaria muito diferente do `$_POST`, apenas colocaria tudo em um aray para evitar algum possivel conflito

Na validação:

```
$_SESSION['form_foo'] = $_POST;
```

No form:

```
<input type="text" value="<?=isset($_SESSION['form_foo']['nome'])?$_SESSION['form_foo']['nome']:''?>" name="nome">
```

Comment: Só funciona se a requisição está sendo tratada na mesma página que o formulário.

Comment: Minha requisição é tratada em uma página diferente do formulário.

Comment: @MuriloSouza então a _$_SESSION_ é uma boa opção.

Comment: Se ao invés de fazer um redirect vc fizer include da página com o form no fim do script,  dá pra usar as variáveis de post e get ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Se a requisição for tratada no mesmo arquivo, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/184017/5878) do Marcos, em que utiliza-se diretamente a variável `$_POST`, é válida. Caso haja a necessidade de se tratar a requisição em arquivos distintos, acredito que `session` não é a melhor saída, mas sim `cookie`. Embora pareçam ser iguais, a finalidade é diferente. Requisições HTTP são caracterizadas como *stateless*, pois não persistem dados entre múltiplas requisições, assim que é obtido a resposta à requisição os dados são perdidos. O objetivo de `session` e `cookie` é exatamente persistir por um tempo alguns dados que sejam interessantes à aplicação em questão, a diferença é que a `session` persiste os dados no lado do servidor e os `cookies` persistem os dados do lado do usuário. <strike>Visto que estamos trabalhando com um formulário, em que o próprio usuário fornecerá os dados, não apresenta nenhum risco à aplicação persistir os dados no lado do usuário</strike>. Para o servidor, só interessa os dados quando os mesmos já forem válidos.

Uma discussão sobre isso pode ser lida aqui:

- [Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115190)

Desta forma, seu formulário pode ser definido seguindo a mesma lógica apresentada na outra resposta, mas agora substituindo a variável `$_POST` por `$_COOKIE`:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= isset($_COOKIE['form_foo']['nome']) ? $_COOKIE['form_foo']['nome'] : '' ?>" name="nome">
```

E no arquivo que trata as requisições, após validar os dados, persistí-los através da função [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: _"não apresenta nenhum risco à aplicação persistir os dados no lado do usuário"_ não dá pra concordar com isso. Não se deve confiar em nada que vem do _client-side_. A boa prática é sempre desconfiar e tratar os dados no _PHP_, pois risco sempre tem.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda, mas há a validação. Essa persistência é apenas para apresentar os dados novamente no formulário.

Comment: mesmo assim haverá risco para a aplicação, principalmente porque os dados podem ser manipulados pelo cliente.

Comment: Essa é a ideia. Para isso que existe o formulário. Se o usuário digitou no campo do e-mail "usuario#gmail.com", será inválido na validação no servidor e voltará ao formulário com esta informação já preenchida. Se ele, de alguma forma, alterar o valor, será novamente validado pelo servidor até possuir algo válido. Qual é o risco?

Comment: O risco é _Cross-Site Request Forgery_, mas existem outros. É possível manipular as informações num _cookie_ pra devolver comandos arbitrários para o navegador. Não se deve confiar cegamente no _browser_, e às vezes a validação no lado do servidor não é suficiente.

Comment: Mas estamos falando de repovoamento de um formulário, não autenticação do usuário.

Comment: Como eu disse, existem outros riscos, e _CSRF_ não está vinculada apenas aos dados de autenticação. Veja bem, eu só não concordei com o fato de vc dizer que o uso de _cookie_ para recuperar dados _não apresenta risco_, só isso.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda, eu entendo. Parece que isso estava além do meu conhecimento. Tirarei esta afirmação para não causar confusão.