# Como recuperar parametro de um Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, parâmetros, asp.net-identity

Apôs o usuário realizar o login, é passado dois parâmetros para `Controller Home`:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
{
   //recupera as informações do usuario que corresponda ao usuario e password
   var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Usuário, model.Password);

   //redireciona o login para o index o controller home
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { 
           cod_cli = user.cod_cli, 
           razao_social = user.razao_social 
   });
}
```

Porém, em outra pagina tenho um botão que também redireciona para `Action Index` do `Controller Home`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("OneeWeb", "Index", "Home", new { 
      area = "", 
      cod_cli = "parametro1", 
      razao_social = "parametro2" 
}, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

Minha duvida é, como eu recupera esses parâmetros? eles não mudam, são fixos para cada usuário.

Neste caso, seria bom guardar esses parametros no `Cookie`?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, ao começar a trabalhar com `Sessions`.

Para maiores informaçoes: [Qual a diferença entre Sessions e Cookies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115190/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-sessions-e-cookies/115197#115197)

Apôs login do usuario, é obtido o objeto com os dados do usuario:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
                {
                    //recupera as informações do usuario que corresponda ao usuario e password
                    var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Usuário, model.Password);                       
                    Session["cod_cli"] = user.cod_cli;
                    Session["razao_social"] = user.razao_social;

                    //redireciona o login para a pagina que o usuario estava.
                    //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    //redireciona o login para o index o controller home
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { cod_cli = Session["cod_cli"], razao_social = Session["razao_social"] });
                }
```

E então, utilizo duas `Session` para "guardar" os dados que precisos, e então utilizar em outras paginas..