# Session vs Cookie, qual diferença?

Tags: node.js

Eu tenho uma duvida em Sessions e Cookies no Node, em relaçao ao lugar onde eles sao guardados e como funciona.

A principio sei das seguintes afirmaçoes:

1. Cookies eu posso setar quando tempo ele pode guardar seus dados;
2. A Session guarda os dados enquanto o navegador estiver aberto;
3. Cookies fica no lado do cliente;
4. Session fica no lado do servidor;
5. Session fica dentro do Cookie.

Ai surge as seguintes perguntas:

1. Como o browse e/ou servidor sabe que o usuario ja logou e nao precisa
   logar novamente ?
2. Se a Session fica dentro do Cookie por que existe essa diferença ?
3. A onde o Cookie é guardado ? No nosso browser ?

Uso o passport porem ele faz tudo sozinho, queria entender melhor como funciona por tras dos panos.

Comment: A pergunta é ampla também. E pra falar a verdade a duplicata hoje em dia seria fechada

Comment: @Maniero Nao encontrei respostas sobre minhas perguntas, mas tudo bem. Obrigado

Comment: Session fica dentro do cookie? Essa afirmação está errada, o cookie é uma chave que o servidor utiliza para resgatar a session do cliente em sua memória, ou em um banco de dados/servidor externo.

Comment: Porque as perguntas partem de premissas erradas, então é melhor entender o que é isto antes de ter uma dúvida específica e real.

Comment: **Sobre as afirmações:** 1 você pode pedir pro browser, não significa que ele vá obedecer. 2 a sessão comumente não fica no navegador, só um identificador dela (um valor único). 3 é isso. 4 geralmente é isso. 5 Não, o identificador de uma sessão pode ser passado por diversas outras maneiras, cookie é apenas uma delas. **Sobre as perguntas:** 1 o browser não sabe e não se envolve no processo de login da sua aplicação. 2 ela não fica, 3 fica no browser enquanto o usuário ou o proprio browser não limpa. **Acesse o [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115190/70) para mais detalhes**

Comment: @user140828 quando vemos um request e entramos no cookie, la existe uma 'variavel' session com todas as infos.. pq ?

Comment: As pessoas pensam que entendem HTTP, mas não entendem, e nisto nasce os tipos de duvidas e até confusões sobre o que é sessão, o que é front, o que é back, como a comunicação ocorre de verdade e tem muitos que nos (a mim a você a qualquer um) ensinam errado pq não quiseram aprender o certo, ai você obtem falsas informações e fica com esta falta de compreensão, HTTP é a base da comunicação toda aqui, claro q podemos citar alternativas para sessões ainda sim o transporte é feito por HTTP e do lado cliente nada mais que as tais variaveis são apenas chaves, os valores estão em outro lugar.